# How do I find the probability of these independent events

Tags: probability, gre-exam

The following is taken from the ETS math review for the GRE:

Let A, B, C, and D be events for which P(A or B)=0.6, P(A)=0.2, P(C or D)=0.6, and P(C)=0.5 The events A and B are mutually exclusive, and the events C and D are independent. 
Find P(D).

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how to solve this. The answer is given as 0.2, but I don't know how it's arrived at. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what it means for $A$ and $B$ to be mutually exclusive?  What about for $C$ and $D$ to be independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the independence of $C$ and $D$ we have that
$$
P(C)P(D)=P(C\cap D)=P(C)+P(D)-P(C\cup D).
$$
Use this to find $P(D)$. You don't need to involve $A$ and $B$ to find $P(D)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question from the GRE practice book and the answer is not $0.1$, so the logic for the previous answer given ([edit LL:] by 
user90188) its not correct. I'm almost sure the answer is:

b) $P(C\text{ or }D) = P(C)+P(D)-P(C\text{ and }D)$ since independent events may be NOT mutually exclusive events. 
\begin{align}
P(C\text{ or }D) &= P(C)+P(D)-P(C)*P(D)    \\
0.6 &= 0.5+P(D)-0.5*P(D)     \\
0.6-0.5&=P(D)-0.5*P(D)    \\
0.1&=P(D)-0.5*P(D)    \\
0.1&=P(D)(1-0.5)    \\
0.1/(1-0.5)&=P(D)    \\
0.1/0.5&=P(D)    \\
0.2&=P(D)    \\
\end{align}

Comment: "so the logic for the previous answer given its not correct" Sorry?

Answer (score -2):

P(c∩d)= 0 as they are independent so

p (c∪d)= p(c)+p(d)-P(c∩d)

so p(d)= 0.6-0.5

p(d)=0.1

Comment: $P(C\cap D)$ is not necessarily zero for independent events. I think you're confusing independent with mutually exclusive.